# sendTransaction() method locks running of my app

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions

There is how I launch Geth node:

```
geth --fast --rpc --ipcapi= "admin,eth,personal" --rpcapi= "eth,web3,personal"
```

with following test-only unlocking account:

```
geth --exec 'personal.unlockAccount(eth.coinbase, "psw" ,0)' attach
```

About one-two hour(s) Geth can execute `web3.eth.sendTransaction()` correctly, but later on attempts to execute this fails, the method just locks either my app's running (if it is used in web3-app, even with async callback) or js-console (if it is used with JS-console). There is **no** any exception, just endless locking.

Additional information:

1. Ether is sufficiently
2. Account is not locked
3. `web3.net.listening` returns true
4. `web3.eth.getBlock("latest")` returns a 2-hours-outdated block

So, I see my Geth stopped sync. What can be a cause? Why do not sendTransaction() throw any exception?